# How to rotate image in tensorflow with mode edge?

Tags: python, tensorflow, scikit-image

I was used skimage package to rotate an image that has mode edge option

`image_rotate = skimage.transform.rotate(image, angle,mode='edge')`

> mode : {‘constant’, ‘edge’, ‘symmetric’, ‘reflect’, ‘wrap’}, optional
>   Points outside the boundaries of the input are filled according to the given mode. Modes match the behaviour of numpy.pad.

Right now, I am using tensorflow function

```
tf.contrib.image.rotate(
    images,
    angles,
    interpolation='NEAREST'
)
```

How can I use `tf.contrib.image.rotate` to obtain the result as `mode='edge'` in the skimage package? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`tf.contrib.image.rotate` does not implement padding. If you'd like to pad your image before rotating it, you'll have to do that yourself using tensorflow operations.

Comment: Thanks so much. Could you give me some script/code to do it in tensorflow for your idea?